# jackson List<Map<String, String>> to xml

Tags: java, xml, json, jackson, resteasy

I have class like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "info")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Data
public class BasketInfoResult extends FibResult {

    private List<Map<String, String>> items;
}
```

How to map it on XML? Resteasy map it in json without errors but when I try to get xml i got an error

> 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions

Answer (score 1):

Jackson is a JSON processor. It cannot map to XML. For that you will need something else, maybe JAX-B or Castor?

**Edit:**

This is a "feature" of JAXB. The simplest workaround is to create a wrapper class for your List. Something like this should work:

```
public class SensibleNameForWrapperClass {
    private List<Map<String, String>> value;

    public List<Map<String, String>> getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(List<Map<String, String>> value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Jackson _can_ do XML. Not in jackson-databind but wiht a dedicated module.

Comment: i user resteasy as jaxrs. In simple examples all goes as expected and any data I have converts to xml but this List<Map<String, String>> not

Comment: Oh. That's because JAXB doesn't do lists. I will update my answer to reflect his.

Comment: Thanks. But this doesn't works too :) But your answer were very helpful.  I change field declaration to List <SensibleNameForWrapper> and in wrapper value field contains only map (not list of map).